# Vaadin 7 check if style name exists

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin 7 application I can add a new style name to a component for example via following method:

```
panel.addStyleName("criteria-menu-active");
```

But right the next click on this component I need to check if this style was already added to this component and if so - remove it.

So, how to test the component for the presence of a certain style by its name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the following?

```java
myLayout.addStyleName("custom-style");
System.out.println("Style = " + myLayout.getStyleName());
```

Output:

```
Style = custom-style
```

Comment: When multiple styles are assigned, https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#getStyleName() returns all of them, with blank separated. If that's the case you have to parse the returned string and break up the stylenames

Comment: Thanks. Is it the only way to do this ? Honestly I expected some more abstract functionality out of the box like for example `boolean hasStyleName(String styleName)`

Comment: @alexanoid i'm not aware of anything like that. I suppose there aren't really many use cases for it, and what's already there is enough to support whatever corner cases the users have.

Comment: @alexanoid the .*StyleName are just the helpers around the actual state.  this "has" function is basically `getState().styles?.contains('class')`